# Virtualenv django project created through ubuntu, checkout out to a windows machine not cross os compatible?

Tags: django, virtualenv

I've created a django project with virtualenv on my server. It is an Ubuntu server. I have checked it into svn.
Now I'm on a windows machine and have checked out the project. I noticed however that the activate and deactivate scripts are in bash when created through linux and are .bat files in windows. Furthermore the pip on my windows machine is a exe file where on the project created through ubuntu it's not.

**My question** then is: is there anyway to setup my windows environment so that I'm able to work from a windows machine (perhaps installing bash on windows or something), is there something I can do when creating the project through ubuntu to allow for this perhaps
 or will I be limited to working on this kind of project via linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could install cygwin.

But you're doing it wrong, really. You shouldn't be checking your virtualenv into your repo - just your code. Your code should contain everything you need to recreate your virtualenv on the target machine, which basically just means a requirements.txt file which you pass to pip to reinstall the relevant libraries.

Comment: OK thanks for the advice. You're right I'm not doing this right. So when I create the project on the server I would use pip passing the requirements. then when i checkout i would do the same with pip and the requirements... have you any guides or good docs i can follow regarding this kind of setup?